# Hibernate dialect for Oracle Database 18c?

Tags: hibernate, oracle-rac, oracle18c

Is there a Hibernate dialect for Oracle Database 18c? Or should I use the `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect` that ships with Hibernate?

When using Hibernate 5.3 and Oracle 18c RAC is there anything special the application has to take care of?

Comment: Oracle 18c is essentially a 12.3 just with a "modern" naming scheme. So the `Oracle12cDialect` should work just fine

Comment: Did this worked for you ? I am having the same issue with oracle 19

Comment: @NullPointerException yes, it worked for me but i can't advice with confidence that this will work for everyone.

Comment: There was a bug in version 5.3 and lower. I had to upgrade to version 5.4 to get this working Someone answered me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57715024/hibernate-dialect-for-oracle-19)

Comment: Tried with Oracle12cDialect and Oracle 18 DB. Get error `Could not fetch the SequenceInformation from the database`. This [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58570032/hibernate-could-not-fetch-the-sequenceinformation-from-the-database) will helped me. Issue with Oracle Sequance max value too large for Java Long

Answer (score 6):

At the time of writing this comment with the latest version of Hibernate (5.4.10), **there is no official dialect for Oracle18 in Hibernate**.

When there are no major differences in the Database dialect, a special dialect is not usually created for him in Hibernate.

For example, I used the Oracle10 dialect with Oracle11 without major problems in production environments.
The same for Oracle 18, the Oracle12 dialect should work without major problems.

Keep in mind that Oracle release numbers are no longer numbered as in the past, and today they are related to the release year (so the larger number does not mean exactly that there are major changes in your dialect).

About Oracle Database release numbers: [release number](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/upgrd/oracle-database-release-numbers.html)

As a comment, if you don't use the new features of Oracle 18, there is also the possibility of configuring Oracle to be compatible with a certain previous version (11 or 12 in this case). However, it is recommend not to use this config if it's possible solved with a custom Dialect or modifying your software.

About Oracle Database Compatible parameter: [compatible parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/upgrd/what-is-oracle-database-compatibility.html)

I hope this helps others who are looking for the same.