# Hibernate Dialect for Oracle 19

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, oracle19c

One of our database was upgraded to Oracle 19c and now my application is unable to connect to database

I am getting the following error.

```
HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Unable to determine Dialect to use [name=Oracle, majorVersion=19]; user must register resolver or explicitly set 'hibernate.dialect'
```

I searched for dialect for oracle 19 but could't find any .

Is there is a dialect available for oracle 19 ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There isn't a newer dialect than 12c, and it would be fine to use it with 19c, but there was a bug in hibernate-orm that prevents the auto detection to work, see:

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13184

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13609

It is already solved in the newer 5.4 releases, and I opened a PR for the 5.3 branch.

A workaround for now is to manually set the dialect property `hibernate.dialect` to `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect`.

Comment: The property is already set to use `Oracle12cDialect`. The version I didn't checked. I believe I am using 5.3 and will give a try with 5.4

Comment: Oracle12cDialect is deprecated in Hibernate 6, I get the following error message when using it: "WARN  [org.hibernate.orm.deprecation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 84) HHH90000026: Oracle12cDialect has been deprecated; use org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect instead". When I use OracleDialect instead, I get "HHH000064: The OracleDialect dialect has been deprecated" instead :s

Answer (score 11):

Note that autodetection has changed in **Hibernate 6**, see the [migration guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/migration-guide/migration-guide.html#_dialects).

> As a result, version-specific dialects (e.g. `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect`) should no longer be used. Use this dialect `org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect` instead, and ignore its deprecated subclasses: