# How to properly configure: spring boot / jpa / hibernate and oracle 19c

Tags: java, mysql, spring, oracle, spring-boot

I have strange problem. I can't run my `spring` app when I change connection from MySQL to Oracle (19c). 
When I am using MySQL everything is fine. My app is really simple, its doing nothing, it is sample empty project for test connection.

Here is my **application.properties (MySQL)**:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fckOracle
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = student
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

and part of **pom.xml (MySQL)**,

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>mysql</groupId>
     <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
     <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Here is my **application.properties (Oracle 19c)**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
spring.datasource.username=ALBERT
spring.datasource.password=student
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

and part of **pom.xml (Oracle 19c)**

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
     <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Okay, when I am trying to run my app with oracle connection, compiler can't load dialect. Program is frozen and localhost:8080 doesn't work, and here is my console:
[image]

I have tried a lot of dialects *Oracle12cDialect, Oracle10gDialect*..., result is always the same, with one exception! When I change the dialect to this:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
```

My app starts, but with error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

localhost8080 is working, but I cant do any operation on my oracle database.

**Anyone have idea how to fix this oracle configuration?**

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57715024/hibernate-dialect-for-oracle-19

Comment: Well, yes i saw that but i am not full understand what is the problem. Did hibernate get some bug with dialect 12c? In that post, that guy said, "It is already solved in the newer 5.4 releases"
My version of hibernate is 5.4.9.Final. Then i think this problem does not concern me, is it?

Comment: did you try setting your dialect to `hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect` and remove any other properties related to other **database dialects**.

Comment: did you tried ```<dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
      <version>19.3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>```

Comment: Santossh Kumhar, i did :/ 

RamPrakash, i tried this and i get that error:
https://textuploader.com/1oycz

Comment: Which version Java are you using?

Comment: java 1.8 ......

Comment: The exception message is self-explanatory: table or view does not exist. There is a missing table or view in your database schema, that your application needs. It has nothing to do with a dialect (which shouldn't be set to  HSQLDialect, since you're using Oracle, and not MySQL).

Comment: JB Nizet, if i change dialect to (for example): Oracle12cDialect, i dont have any errors. My app is frozen while loading dialect.

Comment: What makes you think it's frozen? And why do you set the dialect instead of letting Hibernate discover which one to use by itself?

Comment: It's frozen because my localhost:8080 doesn't work. And any java code after line "SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);" aren't executed.
When i change my database connection to MySQL, everything is okay (localhost:8080 works) and java code after that line "springapplication.run" are executed

Comment: If i will set dialect or i will not, it really doesn't matter. Problem is the same. My program is frozen while loading dialect. When i am using MySQL i dont have that problem.

Comment: `And any java code after line "SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);" aren't executed.` What lines of code are you talking about?

Comment: Well i meant that was that line which is executing in spring apps to launch app. That was all my program, only that line. If i put some code under that line spring.run, this code won't be executed. That was happen when i was using oracle instead of mysql.

Doesn't matter now... I donwloaded oracle 11gR2 and that was solution to my problem :/

Comment: Can you please show your Applicaton class?

Comment: https://textuploader.com/1oy25

Answer (score 1):

I have exact same issue, one thing that helps is to use old ojdbc8 driver for oracle DB, so replace your existing one with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But I would love to see the solution for newer drivers, because I have exact same problem and I have to use 19.3.0.0 drivers

Also about this error

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Try setting `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `update` or `create-drop`. This way Hibernate will generate schema and tables automaticaly and also drop them (when used `create-drop`). It is especially usefull, when you are still experimenting with model of your application.